# Get the text of the next attribute

Tags: jquery

I am looking at getting text of the next attribute (class) of what I currently clicked on. Something like this...

```
$(this).next().attr('class').text();
```

Thanks

**Edit**

Here is my HTML

```
<span class="Directory"></span>
<span class="Category">My Account</span>
```

I want to get the text of class 'Category' when I click on class 'Directory'

Comment: I don't understand what you need. Do you want the name of the class? Just remove `.text()`. Could you show example HTML and what you want to get from it?

Comment: Just to clarify, given `<div class="foo bar stuff thing">` you want to be able to iterate through the classes?

Comment: Post some HTML and an example of what you want to return.

Comment: `.attr()` already returns a string (see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)), not a jQuery object. Do you mean you want to get the `class` attribute of the next **element**? You cannot click on *attributes* of an element and they are not ordered either, so there is nothing like the "next" attribute. If you want help you have to clarify your question.

Comment: Ok check it out. I added the html.

Comment: just remove .text(). and then go and read the jQuery docs and do some tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `.attr('class')` from the code:

```
$(this).next().text()
```

This gets the text of the next element. For example into a variable:

```
var nextText = $(this).next().text();
```

If there may be some other element between the directory element and the category element, you can use a selector to look for the next element with that specific class:

```
$(this).next('.Category').text()
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa. I tend to make things harder than what they are

Answer (score 0):

you can put the class name in a variable like so:

```
var class = $(this).next().attr('class');
```

to get the name of the class, and a hacky way to use that would be :

```
   $('.'+class).text();
```

but if you just want the text of the next element use:

```
   $(this).next().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/muA6R/

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
    alert($(this).next().attr('class'));
});
```

You don't need `.text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(this).next().attr('class')
```

if you want the value of class attribute for the next sibling.

Use

```
$(this).next().text()
```

if you want the text inside the next sibling.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nzhAy/11/) jsfiddle for what i tried

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nzhAy/14/) jsfiddle for your html

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will get the text of the next `span` element with class `Category`.

```
$(this).next().text();
```

`$(this).next().attr('class')` will give you the class name of the next element.

Answer (score 0):

Handle click event of first element, get the next sibling, then get the text.

```
$('.Directory').click(function(){
    alert($(this).next().text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get to next span has class named Category

http://jsfiddle.net/sz9A7/

```
$(function() {
    $("span.Directory").click(getText);
});

function getText() {
    alert($(this).next('span.Category').text());
}
```